# Excel VBA and formula with quotes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, quotes

I know this has been asked several times, but even looking at some examples I can't figure it out.
I have this formula that I need to be written thru VBA:

```
if($B3 <> "", sum($B4:$B10), "")
```

B3, B4 and B10 are actually variables in my VBA code.

In a sort of "meta" code, I know I must write something like this:

`students.Cells(StartRow, StartColumn).Formula = "=If($ColStr & StartRow <> "", Sum(ColStrBegin & StartRow : & ColStrEnd & StartRow), "")`

but I'm really struggling with quotes and double quotes.

I'd really appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: `"=If($" & ColStr & StartRow & "<> """", Sum(" & ColStrBegin & StartRow & ":" & ColStrEnd & StartRow & "), """")"`

Comment: Thank you so much, now I'm starting to understand how to use "!